# Intersect (SEL_OP_AND) not working, but all other selection types are fine

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, source-code

Working on a diff that will allow some more selection options. [Devtalk Post with Build and Diff and Description](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/decoupling-x-ray-and-limit-selection-to-visible/3498/419)

Mainly for Select Through, which is essentially just accessing X-Ray selection in different ways. The inital work was done here: [Blender Differential Link](https://developer.blender.org/D6322), and I'm just adding different features on top of this.

Blender does face selection in X-Ray only by facedot/face center. This diff has added the ability to select faces by area in X-Ray, similar to non-xray face selection, without needing to actually be in X-Ray at the same time. If the selection area (box, lasso, or circle select) is touching any part of the face it should select it. This works in every mode except Intersect (SEL_OP_AND).

```
int ED_select_op_action_deselected(const eSelectOp sel_op,
                                   const bool is_select,
                                   const bool is_inside)
{
  switch (sel_op) {
    case SEL_OP_ADD:
      return (!is_select && is_inside) ? 1 : -1;
    case SEL_OP_SUB:
      return (is_select && is_inside) ? 0 : -1;
    case SEL_OP_SET:
      /* Only difference w/ function above. */
      return is_inside ? 1 : -1;
    case SEL_OP_AND:
      return (is_select && is_inside) ? -1 : (is_select ? 0 : -1);
    case SEL_OP_XOR:
      return (is_select && is_inside) ? 0 : ((!is_select && is_inside) ? 1 : -1);
  }
  BLI_assert_msg(0, "invalid sel_op");
  return -1;
}
```

If an intersect selection is performed, it will either do nothing, or deselect 1 or 2 random faces. [Link to Devtalk post with video example](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/decoupling-x-ray-and-limit-selection-to-visible/3498/429) What should be happening, is when doing a box select, if any of the faces inside the selection area are already selected, select them, and if any of the faces are either not selected already, or outside the selection area, deselect them.

Here is the original code, it is a little more straightforward and has the same result. I have rewritten it recently to use BMesh data for performance reasons, and added some options to select either partially enclosed faces or fully enclosed faces. It works the same, and the video example is using the original code which I'll post here:

Pretty sure this is the important part, will put all of it at the end in case, but wanted to make it concise as possible:

If user wants to do this type of selection, do the following

```
mesh_foreachScreenFaceVerts(
            vc, do_mesh_box_select__doSelectFace, &data, V3D_PROJ_TEST_CLIP_NEAR | V3D_PROJ_TEST_CLIP_BB);
```

Setup coordinates and get data ready

```
void mesh_foreachScreenFaceVerts(ViewContext *vc,
                                 void (*func)(void *userData,
                                              BMFace *efa,
                                              const float screen_co[][2],
                                              int total_count,
                                              rctf *screen_rect,
                                              bool *face_hit),
                                 void *userData,
                                 const eV3DProjTest clip_flag)
{
  Mesh *mesh = editbmesh_get_eval_cage_from_orig(
      vc->depsgraph, vc->scene, vc->obedit, &CD_MASK_BAREMESH);
  BKE_mesh_wrapper_ensure_mdata(mesh);
  ED_view3d_check_mats_rv3d(vc->rv3d);

  BM_mesh_elem_table_ensure(vc->em->bm, BM_FACE);

  const MVert *mvert = mesh->mvert;
  const MPoly *mp = mesh->mpoly;
  const MLoop *ml;
  const BMFace *efa;

  float temp_screen_co[2];
  int total_length = 0;

  float(*screen_coords)[2] = MEM_mallocN(sizeof(int) * 2 * mesh->totvert, __func__);
  int face_screen_verts_size = 4;
  float(*face_screen_verts)[2] = MEM_mallocN(sizeof(int) * 2 * face_screen_verts_size, __func__);

  /* This makes only sense on subdivided meshes.*/
  BLI_bitmap *faces_visited;
  int cage_index = BKE_modifiers_get_cage_index(vc->scene, vc->obedit, NULL, 1);
  const bool cage_display = cage_index != -1;
  if (cage_display) {
    faces_visited = BLI_BITMAP_NEW((size_t)mesh->totpoly, __func__);
  }

  /* Transform and store all visible verts into screen coords. */
  for (int i = 0; i < mesh->totvert; i++, mvert++) {

    if (mvert->flag & ME_HIDE) {
      continue;
    }

    if (ED_view3d_project_float_object(vc->region, mvert->co, &temp_screen_co, clip_flag) ==
        V3D_PROJ_RET_OK) {
      screen_coords[i][0] = temp_screen_co[0];
      screen_coords[i][1] = temp_screen_co[1];
    }
    else {
      screen_coords[i][0] = 0.0f;
      screen_coords[i][1] = 0.0f;
    }
  }

  const int *poly_index = CustomData_get_layer(&mesh->pdata, CD_ORIGINDEX);
  const bool use_original_index = poly_index != 0;

  rctf poly_rect_data;
  rctf *poly_rect = &poly_rect_data;
  bool face_hit = false;

  /* Collect polygon verts and send off per poly callback. */
  for (int i = 0; i < mesh->totpoly; i++, mp++) {
    int original_index = i;
    if (use_original_index) {
      original_index = *poly_index++;
      if (original_index == ORIGINDEX_NONE) {
        continue;
      }
    }

    if (cage_display && BLI_BITMAP_TEST(faces_visited, original_index)) {
      continue;
    }

    efa = BM_face_at_index(vc->em->bm, original_index);
    if (!BM_elem_flag_test(efa, BM_ELEM_HIDDEN)) {

      if (mp->totloop > face_screen_verts_size) {
        face_screen_verts_size = mp->totloop;
        MEM_freeN(face_screen_verts);
        face_screen_verts = MEM_mallocN(sizeof(float) * 2 * face_screen_verts_size, __func__);
      }

      total_length = 0;
      BLI_rctf_init_minmax(poly_rect);
      ml = &mesh->mloop[mp->loopstart];

      bool skip = false;

      for (int j = 0; j < mp->totloop; j++, ml++) {
        face_screen_verts[j][0] = screen_coords[ml->v][0];
        face_screen_verts[j][1] = screen_coords[ml->v][1];

        /* Ignore polygons with invalid screen coords. */
        if (face_screen_verts[j][0] == 0.0f && face_screen_verts[j][1] == 0.0f) {
          skip = true;
          break;
        }

        total_length++;

        BLI_rctf_do_minmax_v(poly_rect, screen_coords[ml->v]);
      }

      if (skip) {
        continue;
      }

      face_hit = false;

      func(
          userData, efa, (const float(*)[2])face_screen_verts, total_length, poly_rect, &face_hit);

      if (cage_display && face_hit) {
        BLI_BITMAP_ENABLE(faces_visited, original_index);
      }
    }
  }

  if (cage_display) {
    MEM_freeN(faces_visited);
  }
  MEM_freeN(screen_coords);
  MEM_freeN(face_screen_verts);
}
```

Process this data and choose what faces should be selected

```
static void do_mesh_box_select__doSelectFace(
    void *userData, BMFace *efa, const float screen_co[][2], int total_count, rctf *screen_rect, bool *face_hit)
{
  BoxSelectUserData *data = userData;

  if (!BLI_rctf_isect(data->rect_fl, screen_rect, NULL))
    return;

  bool inside = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < total_count; i++) {

    int a = i;
    int b = (i + 1) % total_count;

    inside = edge_inside_rect(data->rect_fl, screen_co[a], screen_co[b]);
    if (inside) {
      break;
    }
  }

  /* Single point check should be suffienct as we only care if the box rect is inside of the
  polygon. */
  if (!inside) {
    float point[2] = {data->rect_fl->xmax, data->rect_fl->ymax};
    inside = isect_point_poly_v2(point, screen_co, total_count, true);
  }

  *face_hit = inside;

  const bool is_select = BM_elem_flag_test(efa, BM_ELEM_SELECT);
  const int sel_op_result = ED_select_op_action_deselected(data->sel_op, is_select, inside);

  if (sel_op_result != -1) {
    BM_face_select_set(data->vc->em->bm, efa, sel_op_result);
    data->is_changed = true;
  }
}
```

I've tried to reason my way through this but I'm getting a little run out of ideas at this point. My assumption is that there is some kind of data loss, seems to only show itself with intersect though, because all other selection types are fine as far as I can tell. Here is a link to a diff of the original work, ported to 3.1.2

[Dropbox link to diff](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9aql2syro9zpqgz/312sthrukio.diff?dl=0)